# Ошибка вызова get - метода

Tags: java, массивы, get

В общем есть код, с которого нужно использовать get-методы, для того чтобы проверить String или, например, массивы, которые будут генерированы с интернет страницы... Не могу вызвать почему-то геттеры на проверку с другого класса.
Код GET-ов -

```
        public String getContent() {
        return content;
        }
        public long getTime() {
        return time;
        }
        public String[] getWords() {
        return words;
        }
        public String[] getLinks() {
        return urls;
        }
```

мои методы в другом классе-

```
public static String mF() {
            int counter = 0;
            int counter2 = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < getWords.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < getWords.length; j++){
                    if (getWords[i].equals(GetWords[j])) {
                        counter++;
                }
            }
                if(counter2 < counter) {
                    counter2 = counter;
                    oftGet = getWords[i];
                }
                counter = 0;
        }
                return oftGet;
    }
```

Метод красный и не хочет работать, дает ошибку в вызове get - метода!
Попытка внедрить что-то в видe -

```
String[] getWords = (new DP()).getWords();
```

дает также ошибку.. Подскажите пожалуйста как поступить в этой ситуации и также сделать мой метод не statik?
В другом классe, в котором написан код и созданы гет методы рабочий 100000%!

Comment: Здесь я хочу проверить массив на часто встречаемое слово в нем, метод работает, но не могу правильно вызвать метод с другого класса через get метод

Comment: Сделайте минимальный пример, потому что ничего непонятно.

Comment: @Igor Например класс1 - там загрузится массив String[] words = { "privet","poka","spasibo","poschaluista","kuku","reku"}; К этому массиву прилагается гет метод в этом же классе - public String[] getWords() { return words } --- Как мне проверить этот массив в другом классе? Не получается вызвать этот метод в другом классе, например, на похожие слова.

Comment: @Igor на похожие слова проверить или подобные операции сделать...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
String[] getWords = new DP().getWords();
```